# How can I hide different sets of ActiveX checkboxes in Excel based on two variables?

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, excel-2021

I'm really new at VBA, so I apologize.  Hopefully I can describe well enough.  I recently changed a section of my spreadsheet from an area I can completely white out with conditional formatting to an area that is text (which I can white out), but also a row of 13 Active X checkboxes.  This pick shows a setup where box 13 should not be shown.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOJa0.png)

When I white out now, obviously the checkboxes will not do the same.  The main problem lies in that I need certain checkboxes shown based on the value in cell K12 and the value in Z77.  If Z77="N", then all the boxes need to be hidden, no matter what K12 is.  If Z77="Y" and K12="B", then checkboxes 5-13 need to hide.  If Z77="Y" and K12="D", then only box 13 needs to hide.  If Z77="Y" and K12="P", then checkboxes 8-12 need to hide.

And as long as I have you, what would recommend as the best way to learn VBA to be?

I couldn't find anything that suited my needs.

Comment: In terms of 'the best way to learn VBA', you could read this [SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/info) which provides resources, references and additional reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am uncertain about the contents of your sheet. My assumption is that all the checkboxes have been created in a sequential manner. Please try it.

```
Sub demo()
    pat = Split("1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1")
    If [Z77] = "N" Then
        pat = Split("0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0")
    ElseIf [Z77] = "Y" Then
        If [K12] = "B" Then
            pat = Split("1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0")
        ElseIf [K12] = "D" Then
            pat = Split("1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0")
        ElseIf [K12] = "P" Then
            pat = Split("1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1")
        End If
    End If
    For i = 1 To 13
        ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(i).Visible = (pat(i - 1) = 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Q: I tried making it so that Z77 needed to be Y and K11 needed to be G, but couldn't get it to work.
A: It seems like "K11" in your comment is a typo. I have updated the code as follows:

- Added a new branch to check if [K12] equals "G"
- The subroutine (For...Next) will not do nothing if the values for [Z77] and [K12] do not match the expected patterns.

```
Sub demo2()
    Dim pat
    If [Z77] = "N" Then
        pat = Split("0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0")
    ElseIf [Z77] = "Y" Then
        If [K12] = "B" Then
            pat = Split("1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0")
        ElseIf [K12] = "D" Then
            pat = Split("1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0")
        ElseIf [K12] = "P" Then
            pat = Split("1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1")
        ElseIf [K12] = "G" Then
            pat = Split("1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1")
        End If
    End If
    If VBA.IsArray(pat) Then
        For i = 1 To 13
            ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(i).Visible = (pat(i - 1) = 1)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That works almost perfectly!  It does exactly what I need, but it requires me to tell it to run for it to happen.  How can I set it to run on its own?

Comment: Also, the first set of boxes were indeed 1 to 13.  My second set of boxes are 14 to 26.  I changed the necessary reference cells, but am getting subscript out of range for the ActiveSheet.OLEObject(i).Visible - (pat (i - 1) = 1) now.

Comment: Worksheet_Change event is what you are looking for. Changing of K12 or Z77 will trigger the event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 And (.Cells(1).Address = "$Z$77" Or .Cells(1).Address = "$K$12") Then
            ' Code of Sub Demo
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you would like to handle the second set of boxes (14 to 26) with the same logic as before, you can use the following code:

```
For i = 1 To 13
   ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(i+13).Visible = (pat(i - 1) = 1)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you taller_excelhome.  I couldn't get the worksheet_change to work like you described, so I punted.  I created three subs to handle boxes 1-13, 14-26, and 27-39.  Then I did a worksheet_change sub and called the three box subs.  Worked like a charm.  I do have one minor issue.  When Z77 is Y, then the boxes show up.  I tried making it so that Z77 needed to be Y and K11 needed to be G, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I have updated the code. Hope it is what are you looking for.

Comment: Thank you again.  I went around the issue and managed to deactivate the checkbox so when K12=G, you can't select the button which keeps the other checkboxes invisible.  Where there's a will...